# Correct usage of moxios

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios, enzyme, moxios

I'm trying to mock an axios request in a function using moxios. Test is running fine and getting the expected result, but I don't think they way I implemented it is not a best practice at all. Could someone please suggest me a better way to achieve this instead of using `setTimeout()` on tests?

```
....

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchSomething();
}

fetchSomething = () => {
    Axios.get('https://someurl.com/api/1')
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({ data: response.data.data });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.setState(error);
        })
}
....
```

Test I've written:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    moxios.install();
});

afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall();
})

it('should ', async (done) => {
    moxios.wait(() => {
        const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
        request.respondWith({
            status: 200,
            response: { data: 'hello' }
        })
    });
    const wrapper = shallow(<TestComponent />);

    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(wrapper.instance().state.data).toEqual('hello')
        done();
    }, 500)
});
```

Comment: Since the code is working this may be a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a better choice.

```
it('should ', (done) => {
 moxios.wait(() => {
     const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
     request.respondWith({
        status: 200,
        response: { data: 'hello'}
     }).then(() => {
        expect(wrapper.instance().state.data).toEqual('hello');
        done()
     })
 });
});
const wrapper = shallow(<TestComponent />);
```